# How java threats generics programming?

Tags: java, generics

I have a doubt about generic programming in Java.

When C++ compiler founds a reference to a generic function/object (templates) inside the code, it creates a function with the non-generic (concrete) type used (for any type it meet).

I don't know how it works in Java. javac behaviour is the same as the C++ compiler? Or it is managed by JVM at runtime?

Thank you

Comment: Java has type erasure. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: Java uses the most general concrete type that it can safely use. It's often Object, unless some kind of requirement is put on what types can be used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics in Java are purely a compile time construct to ensure type safety - they're erased by the compiler and replaced by the raw equivalent (but guaranteed safe unless you've specifically casted to void that type safety.)

This is a relatively neat way of implementing generics, since no modifications need to be done to the VM or hotspot - just the compiler. As well as the obvious limitation that there's no generic type information available at runtime, it does occasionally pose the limitation that the "generic-free" instance has to make sense also. For instance if I want to do something like:

```
public class CompareMe implements Comparator<Thing>, Comparator<OtherThing> {

    public int compareTo(Thing other) {
        //Blah
    }

    public int compareTo(OtherThing other) {
        //Blah
    }
}
```

...then that's not possible using that form, since the direct generic-free equivalent would be:

```
public class CompareMe implements Comparator, Comparator {

    public int compareTo(Object other) {
        //Blah
    }

    public int compareTo(Object other) {
        //Blah
    }
}
```

...and clearly there's an issue with clashing names there! Of course, this could be re-written using a single comparator, or using a compareTo method with a custom comparator passed in, but it's worth taking note of.

Answer (score 0):

Java generate code for conversion types before compilation. Also java use [type inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference) for get correct type. For example :

```
List <Integer> mylist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
i.add(someInt);
```

In old style you can manually conversuin type:

```
Integer valI = (Integer)mylist.get(index);
```

Today compiler to "know" type elements of `mylist`  and add `(Integer)` by itself. In result you write only it:

```
Integer valI = mylist.get(index);
```